# Swift concurrency async/await with do-something-only-on-success and retry

Tags: swift, completionhandler, swift-concurrency

I'm converting our app's networking to use async/await, and I'm having a little trouble coming up with a satisfactory pattern to replace the completion handler that we were using previously. Here is some pseudo-code of what we do:

```
func loadData() {
    fetchData {
        showTheSearchField()
    }
}

func fetchData(completion: () -> ()) {
    doTheActualNetworking()
    if networkingSucceeded {
        completion()
    } else {
        putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton(buttonAction: {
            fetchData(completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

You see the point here. First we try to fetch the data, which we do by performing actual networking. Then:

- If we succeeded, and *only* if we succeeded, then do whatever the caller wants done in case of success (what I have called `completion`, but perhaps a better name would be `onSuccess`).
- If we failed, put up an alert with a try again button, and the action of that button is to fetch the data *again* and behave just the same way *again* — if we succeed this time, and *only* if we succeed this time, then do whatever the caller wants done in case of success.

My problem is that when I convert to async await, I can't find a way to eliminate the blasted the completion handler. For instance, in my example the completion handler says to show the search field. I can't just wrap the whole thing up as e.g. a throwing async method:

```
func loadData() {
    Task {
        try await fetchData()
        showTheSearchField()
    }
}

func fetchData() async throws {
    do {
        try await doTheActualNetworking()
    } catch {
        putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton(buttonAction: {
            Task {
                try await fetchData()
            }
        }
        throw error
    }
}
```

You see what's wrong with that? If we succeed on `doTheActualNetworking` the first time, fine, we fall back into the task in `loadData` and we proceed to show the search field. But if we fail and put up the alert and the user taps the try again button and we succeed this time, we *won't* show the search field, because we failed and threw and `loadData` came to an end.

So it seems to me that I am *forced*, because of the cyclic nature of the try again button, to maintain the completion / success handler, passing it into `fetchData` so that the try again button can recurse with it, just as I was doing before.

Well, that works fine, of course, but it feels to me like an anti-pattern. I'm adopting async/await exactly because I'd like never to see another completion handler as long as I live. Am I just stuck with the completion handler, or is there a way around this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Can you make `putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton` async too? You can wrap it in a continuation and it can return a `Bool` indicating if the user clicked the button or just dismissed the alert. Then you can do `if await putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton() { try await fetchData() } else { throw error }`. It might be better to do this in a `repeat ... while` loop as well.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to do that. It's literally just a presented view controller; I don't get an event when it's dismissed in any other way than if the user taps the Try Again button. Are you suggesting that the entire view controller present-and-dismiss mechanism be somehow wrapped up as async/await?

Comment: Can you wrap `putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton` in a [`withCheckedContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedcontinuation(function:_:)) block? This might be what Sweeper intended. Edit: looking at it more you'll still be left with a hanging thread and its leaked resources if the button action is never pressed.

Comment: @Daniel yes, that is what I intended. What hanging thread and leaked resources are your talking about? If the button is never pressed, `fetchData` will simply be suspended. The threads will not be blocked and can still run whatever there is to run. And as far as I can see, there is no resources that needs to be disposed/closed in this context.

Comment: @Sweeper Won't the `fetchData` thread be suspended indefinitely and never disposed of (same with the `Task` object that called `fetchData` in the first place)? It doesn't appear to have any significant resources, but the thread state/any local vars will be retained. Nothing important is blocked but this memory management doesn't seem clean. The continuation has to be resumed exactly once, and a `CheckedContinuation` will throw an error like "SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: fetchData() leaked its continuation!" otherwise.

Comment: @Daniel you should not think in terms of threads. Once a function is suspended, Swift can use the thread that that function was running on, for other things. See an example here: https://www.malcolmhall.com/2023/10/15/async-await-uialertcontroller/

Comment: @Sweeper this example is what I had in mind. But the difference is that in your link, the cancel button also resumes the continuation, which Matt seemed to resist. Putting the word "thread" aside, the continuation object will persist until it is resumed. If the only way to resume it is from the `buttonAction`, then dismissing the popup through a cancel action will result in the continuation being retained indefinitely. My only complaint is about the retention of this object -- not about blocking anything important.

Comment: Is there any prior art for this concept of using async await to await the dismissal of a presented view controller? It seems so alien, somehow.

Comment: @matt This is not exactly the same situation, but most if not all the methods requesting for authorisation of some kind (e.g. [`requestAuthorization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/3616053-requestauthorization) in PhotoKit) work in a similar way. If the user has not authorised the access yet, an alert will show up and `requestAuthorization` only returns after the user chooses an option.

Comment: I prefer to implement presentation logic in a finite state machine (actually a Transducer, aka FST). You have "State" which represents the view, "Event" which enums all events that can happen in the system and a function `(State, Event) -> (State, [Effect])` which performs the logic where Effect is a simple struct encapsulating an async function - here, your "loadData()" function. This function is actually a combination of the _transition_ function and the _output_ function of the FST. The function is synchronous and _pure_,  and usually very concise, clear and easy to get right. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to follow your recursive pattern:

```swift
func loadData() async throws {
    try await fetchData() 
    showTheSearchField()
}

func fetchData() async throws {
    do {
        try await doTheActualNetworking()                // assume throws error if no network 
    } catch NetworkingError.noNetwork {
        try await putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton()      // assume returns if user tapped “try again”, but throws some “user cancelled error”  (or perhaps even `CancellationError`) if user taps on “cancel”
        try await fetchData()
    } catch {
        throw error                                      // for whatever errors you do not want a “retry” option, if any
    }
}
```

Or, obviously, you could also do it non-recursively (perhaps adding some “max retry” logic, too; that’s up to you):

```swift
func fetchData() async throws {
    while true {
        do {
            try await doTheActualNetworking()            // assume throws error if no network
            return                                       // if no error thrown, just return
        } catch NetworkingError.noNetwork {
            try await putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton()  // assume returns if user tapped “try again”, but throws some “user cancelled error” (or perhaps even `CancellationError`) if user taps on “cancel”
        } catch {
            throw error                                  // for whatever errors you do not want a “retry” option, if any
        }
    }
}
```

---

FWIW, to wrap the alert in a continuation in UIKit, for example, it might look like:

```swift
func putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton() async throws { 
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "There was a network error.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try again", style: .default) { _ in
            continuation.resume()
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
            continuation.resume(throwing: CancellationError())
        })
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Or, just wrap your current completion-handler-based function in a continuation:

```swift
func putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton() async {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton {
            continuation.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I would be inclined to give the “retry” UI a “cancel” option (so the user isn’t stuck in an endless loop if they happen to be in a no-network scenario) and then give the completion-handler a parameter indicating the result of which button they tapped. And in that case, we would then use a throwing continuation, like the `UIAlertController` example, but it comes down to whether the app is really completely dependent upon the presence of a functioning network connection or not. Obviously, if there is no “cancel” option, it would be a non-throwing continuation, and you would eliminate the `try` in the calls, but the idea is the same.

There are lots of variations on the theme, but hopefully it illustrates the idea.

Comment: Just to get this chit-chat out of here, I've moved it to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257229/discussion-between-rob-and-matt). I'll delete my comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much to @Sweeper and @Rob. Just to help out anyone who wants to see how this turned out:

This was a lot easier to implement than I thought it would be. The solution involved a new pattern of use for `withCheckedContinuation` for me, so this question-and-answer has taught me something important. I'm used to using `withCheckedContinuation` as basically the only thing in an async method (usually returning it implicitly), in converting old non-async/await code into async/await. But it turns out you can say e.g.

```
let response = await withCheckedContinuation...
```

*anywhere* in an async method. That's the game-changing realization for me.

The only hard part was that in our app we already have these Alert objects that have to be configured with their `cancel` and `tryAgain` handlers at initialization time; I can't modify them later on. But I made an additional initializer that takes a Continuation as one of the parameters, so I can form those handlers right there in the initializer. And bingo, it's working perfectly. I was able to turn `fetchData` into a true `async throws` method, with no internal Task and no completion handler, and all the right things are happening.

```
func loadData() {
    Task {
        try await fetchData()
        showTheSearchField()
    }
}

@MainActor func fetchData() async throws {
    try {
        doTheActualNetworking()
    } catch {
        let buttonTapped = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            putUpAnAlertWithATryAgainButton(continuation: continuation)
        }
        switch buttonTapped {
        case .cancel:
            throw error
        case .tryAgain:
            try await fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

This is really easy to read, and it does exactly the right thing. If networking succeeds, we show the search field. If networking fails, we put up the alert. If the user taps cancel, that's a failure and we *don't* show the search field. If the user taps try again, we recurse, and so we attempt to networking again, and everything I just said (starting with the words "If networking succeeds") remains true.